# spring data - MongoDB - java.util.deque

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am getting unsupported datatype java.util.deque when I insert my document in Mongo using spring data. I see Stack and Queue is supported by default and didn't require converters. Do I need to write a converter for Deque. Has anyone faced this before? Please let me know.

Appreciate your help.